# My app failed app review because Facebook tested the wrong version. How can I direct them to the right one?

Tags: review, facebook-app-requests, facebook-permissions

I submitted my app for permissions review and provided all the required info, but somehow the reviewers reviewed the wrong version of the app (they should have reviewed the one in open Beta, which is the currently published version in Google Play). How can I make them see the error of their ways and review the correct version? Please don't tell me I have to put my app into production first; in order to get to production, I need to add code that will make use of the requested permissions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I received a message from Facebook yesterday and straightened them out on which URL to use.